# Paypal with not allowed currency

Tags: magento2, paypal, currency

I use Magento 2 and try to use PayPal but my currency is not allowed by PayPal (Romanian Leu). I make a lot of research to find some extension for that But I don't find :(

Please help me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution for currency conversion ? 
It can convert your currency to paypal support list.
https://github.com/durgagupta/magento2-paypal-currency

Comment: I don't know to instal this plugin. And i don't know if it is trusted.